# Conceptualizing a balance in a DFS traversal

Tags: algorithms, trees

I'm trying to use the concept of DFS traversal to go through a cycle, and attempt to get a balance of 0 in the end. Each student either owes or is owed some money, so I'm trying to go through all of said students and make sure each one can pay the other.

> The input for your algorithm consists of two lists $owing$ and
>   $friendship$. The length of the list $owing$ is the total number of
>   students; $owing[i]$ is the amount that student $i$ is owing $(0 \leq i \leq
>  len(owing)-1)$, and it is an integer than can be positive (owing
>   money), negative (owed money) or zero. The list $friendship$ is a list
>   of pairs that represent the remaining friendships, i.e., a pair $(i, j)$
>   means student $i$ and student $j$ are still friends and can still talk and
>   give money to each other. Devise an efficient algorithm which, given
>   the two input lists, returns whether or not it is possible for everyone to get
>   even.

---

I've attempted to write psuecode for it, and it runs in O(|V + E|), the normal runtime of a DFS. I was wondering if it's correct, and whether there's a way to have it run more efficiently?

The general logic behind it is, visited all members in the owing list but paying the debts through friendship. Check that the total sum all frienships in this path can total up to 0. If it doesn't returns failure.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: If you want to know whether your algorithm is correct, try running it on small hand-written test cases, run it on a million randomly generated test cases, then try to write a proof of correctness (and simultaneously, search for a test case where it gives the wrong answer).

Comment: @D.W. I made some modifications to the post, is it okay now or should I change it further?

Comment: I don't see how deleting the pseudocode improves the question. Without your pseudocode, we cannot tell whether your pseudocode is correct.

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/72049/755